# Search filter returning html template instead of data(Jquery) from header.php

Tags: php, jquery

Problem:

Filtering and searching records from DB.

When you type something is should return records from db but it is returning entire `header.php` file as a template. What could be the reason? Here are my jQuery and `header.php` code

**jQuery**

```
$('#searchbox').on('keyup focus', function(e) {
  var b = $(this).attr();
  delete b.class, delete b.placeholder, delete b.id, delete b.name, delete b.type, delete b.autocomplete;
  b.q = $(this).val();
  f(b.q != '' && b.q.length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: api,
      data: b,
      cache: false,
      success: function(b) {
        $("#livesearch").html(b);
        $("#livesearch").fadeIn();
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("#livesearch").fadeOut();
  }
});

$('#searchbox').on('blur', function(e) {
  $('#livesearch').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: There is no PHP code given...

Comment: Possible typo: `f (b.q != '' && b.q.length > 0) {`

Comment: "it is returning entire header.php file as a template. What could be the reason?" Presumably your `api` points to header.php and it returns the whole thing. Some logic in there is not understanding the values passed to it, _or_ the values passed to it are not correct. Show a) your PHP code, b) the values you are passing in, c) the response you expected to get based on those values. Until you do that, it's not possible to say what the problem is.